# Spark interaction with Kafka with two different principals

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I have the following question.
I'm using a Spark Structured Streaming job which reads from one topic and writes to another topic of the same kerberized Kafka cluster. Everything works super.

But my problem is the following: How would I handle the case in which I have for each of these 2 topics different principals and keytab.

- Should I submit two JAAS files (one for each principal/keytab) to Spark? If yes, how can this be achieved?
- Can I put both "KafkaClient" declarations into one JAAS file?

Thank you very much.